# Invalid cross-device link when attempting to run ‘sudo apt-get -f install’

Tags: ubuntu, apt

When I attempt to run `sudo apt-get -f install` I get the this:

```
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.4-stdlib_3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.7) over (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.4-stdlib_3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to move aside `./usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/error.py' to install new version: Invalid cross-device link
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.4-stdlib_3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.7_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how I can fix it?
This is on Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-042stab144.1 x86_64)

Thanks

Comment: Contact your VPS provider. It looks like a problem with their storage.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server is this? Your kernel version doesn't look like a stock Ubuntu kernel, so this might be some sort of virtual server with kernel provided by someone else. As such it might be worth asking them if this is a known issue. The kernel version for Ubuntu 14.04 identifies itself as 3.13.0-170.220.

Failing that I would report that as a bug against the python3.4 package here

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4

In the meantime you could possibly try forcing it to install with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.4-stdlib_3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.7_amd64.deb
```

followed by:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: It's a VM hosted by a company called Server4You, I believe in Germany. I've tried both commands you mention but neither works (same error). Next I'll contact the hosting company as per your suggestion (and a previous comment by Michael Hampton)

Comment: The hosting company say it's nothing they can help with :(